# How to loop SWF file loaded with Loader?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to loop a swf file that has been loaded with via the Loader class in AS3.
My code looks as following:

```
public class MyLoader extends MovieClip {
    public function MyLoader() {
        var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("external-movie.swf");
        myLoader.load(url);
        myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener("complete", function() {
      });
      addChild(myLoader);
    }
}
```

From what I understand the Loader has no event for when the embedded movie is finished? Is there a way to figure that out? It must not be a AS3 implementation. I just want a movie that has been exported from Indesign to run in a loop. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a tip: You should add your complete listener before you load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially when you have little experience programming you should avoid dirty shortcuts as they'll only get you a lot of trouble. So avoid anonymous function and avoid using string in place of static event variables.
This being said, if your loaded movie has its own timeline then it will be converted into a MovieClip. Also that movie is not embedded but loaded and that's a big difference.

Keep a reference of that movie and the loader:

```
private var theLoadedMovie:MovieClip;
private var myLoader:Loader;
```

Listen for the INIT event instead of the COMPLETE event (movies with timeline start to play when their first frame is loaded "INIT", the COMPLETE event fires when the whole movie is loaded).

```
myLoader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("external-movie.swf");
myLoader.load(url);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, handleInit);
```

In your handleInit method keep a reference of that movie:

```
theLoadedMovie = myLoader.content as MovieClip;
addChild(theLoadedMovie);
theLoadedMovie.addEventListener(Event.ENTERFRAME, handleEnterFrame);
```

in your handleEnterFrame method check the movie progress to know when it has ended:

```
if(theLoadedMovie.currentFrame == theLoadedMovie.totalFrames)
{
     //movie has reached then end
}
```

Comment: You should add your loader listeners before you use `load()`. There are certain circumstances where it may return from the load before finishing executing the current thread.

Comment: I would agree this is the best way (+1),  It could also be accomplished with 'addFrameScript` in fewer lines of code - but `addFrameScript` is undocumented and best not to be relied upon.

Comment: This is what happens when copying and pasting. load should happen at the end of course.

Comment: addFrameScript is better but undocumented as you say and harder for beginners to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm actually from a java and javascript background which explains the anonymous function calls ;) As it turned out, the swf file did not have it's own timeline and a call to totalFrames resulted in 2. I figure this is because the file has been created in Indesign. I'm going to accept your answer anyways.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what InDesign might do to the resulting swf. Maybe you can try to find the right movie by looking through the loaded movie display list (which could be made recursive). Something like for(var i:int = 0; i < theLoadedMovie.numChildren -1; i++){var movie:MovieClip = theLoadedMovie.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip; if(movie){trace(movie.totalFrames)}}